# SQLAlchemy Eager Loading with Relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationships

trying (and failing) to wrap my head around how to use SQLAlchemy in the following scenario:

Assume I have a Database such that:

```
A has a (one -> many) relationship to B

B has a (one -> many) relation to C
```

If I want to loop through all the B's given an A, I can do:

```
for b in a.bs:
    print "hello"
```

If I want to loop through all C's that indirectly belong to A, I can do:

```
for b in a.bs:
    for c in b.cs:
        print "hello"
```

However, I am aware that each iteration of the outer-most loop would perform a fresh SQL query.

I am of the understanding that I can use subqueryload to prevent this from happening by doing:

```
for b in session.query( b ).options( subqueryload( B.c ) ).filter_by( B.a_id == a.id ):
    for c in b.cs:
        print "hello"
```

Is that the tidiest way to do it?

Is there not some syntax that lets me start from the actual 'a' object. Perhaps something like:

```
for b in a.bs.options( subqueryload( B.c ) ):
    ...
```

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `subqueryload` an arbitrary join path like this:

```
session.query(A).options(subqueryload(A.b).subqueryload(B.c))
```

This uses three queries and will load `A.b`, and `B.c` for every `B` in `A.b`.

Comment: Thanks for this univerio. If I only wanted the rows that were indirectly related to my object 'a', I would have to do a filter like in my answer above correct? 

If this is the case, am I not able to query directly from the relationship property on the 'a' object. Like: a.bs.options( ... I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @maambmb Oh I think I misunderstood your original question. If you have only one `A` object and you wanted to get `A.b` with `B.c` loaded in each `B`, you have the option of doing the filter as you outlined above, or doing a chained subqueryload (as in my answer) *when you first query for that `A` object*. If you wanted to do `a.b.options`, you have to configure `A.b` to be `lazy="dynamic"`. This makes `A.b` return a `Query` instead of a list, which has its pros and cons.

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing that up for me. It is very much appreciated!